# Building distributable binaries in Unix

Tags: file-permissions, binary-files, redistributable

My intention is to generate distributable binaries - I am doing a ./configure - make - make install in my build machine, and I archived the content of the install directory (the one I gave a prefix to while doing ./configure and make install) and moved it to another machine under another user for testing. Upon testing, I see that the copied files still tries to access some files at a path which was at my build machine - and hence I get `permissions denied` error.
Previously I was thinking that it might be a `tar` issue while extracting, but thanks to [Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/users/22317/daniel-beck) who helped me realize that it has nothing to do with the archiving process.

I do not have root/sudo privileges. The crux is - how do I build in one machine and use the install-files in many others without running into permissions related problems? What are the rules to create universally distributable tarballs?

Thanks.

Comment: Sghosh is a user name. Is it user_01 or user_02?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, yes you're right, what I wanted to say is I am moving files from my userspace to another..edited

Comment: OK -- and what's the `ls -l` and `ls -ln` output after extracting on the destination host?

Comment: So this is the `ls -ln` output - `drwxr-xr-x  2 10036 501 4096 Nov 11 04:52 bin` and `ls -l` gives `drwxr-xr-x  2 user_02 staff 4096 Nov 11 04:52 bin`

Comment: Is this the output for a file (or folder) `user_02` is denied access to?

Comment: Yes you're correct, user_02 gets a `permission denied`. The tarball is actually a compiler install...when user_02 is trying to compile a program using the files, the error is like: `cc1: error: /home/sghosh/rpmbuild/buildroot/open64-gcc-4.2.0/include: Permission denied` - this is the path to the sources under my home - I don't know how this is getting propagated.

Comment: Finally we're getting somewhere. Did you `./configure` on your first machine and forget to do this on the second, or something like that?

Comment: Well, I did a ./configure in the first machine, generated binaries (the install-dir), and am tarballing the install-dir only. So I am not building in the second machine at all...rather using the install-dir as-is after unpacking.

Comment: You need to realize that this has *nothing* to do with the tar file, or how you're creating or extracting it. Your program installation has certain paths hard-coded and just won't work without those. I don't think it's possible to do, if you're not willing to install the program somewhere it's available to all users on both systems. // If you still want to try though, I suggest you completely revise your question, throwing everything currently in there away, especially `tar`, instead ask how to compile that specific program so the result is reusable on a different machine with different paths.

Comment: Yes I do realize now that it is related to how I build, I would revise the question, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that many Unix programs are not relocatable. They will always search for files in the path you give to configure (not relative to it's own location). If you want it to be relocatable, so it can be installed in any user directory (or anywhere else) and still find it's files, where is no other way than to modify the program to behave that way.

There are no generic rules for creating generally distributable tarballs, especially for programs made to be installed from source. Most Unix distributions have some kind of special package system for distributing binaries. The best thing is to use that/those. Most comercial applications that ship as binaries in tarballs use an environment variable to locate it's files and use a wrapper shell script that sets this variable (by searching for the files relative it's own path for example). Then again you probably have to modify the program to behave in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tar --no-same-owner` (for the GNU version) when unpacking the tarball. `--no-same-permissions` could also be useful.

Comment: I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: @Sayan who owns these files? They should be owned by the extracting user if given this option. Do you use gnu tar which has this option, or something else?

Comment: Umm, please help me understand - I tar a bunch of files giving +x options...and then I upload it to a website where any user could download and use it; so how do I set the ownership/permission for any user who downloads the tarball? Yes I am using gnu tar.

Comment: @Sayan You don't. While you can set `chmod` like permissions for the included files using the `--mode` argument to GNU `tar`, it's the responsibility of the extracting user to discard the original ownership of the files in the tar ball. For example, I downloaded OpenSSH source code today. `tar tzvf filename.tar.gz` lists the files as owned by the "snap" user, `tar tzvf --numeric-owner filename.tar.gz` shows it's numeric user ID 1018. On my system, there is no such user. I, as the user extracting the archive, need to take care of specifying `--no-same-owner` or `--owner MyUserName`.

Comment: @Sayan This only happens when you extract as root though, since other users aren't able to create files belonging to a different user. It would help if you explained in detail how you create and extract the tar archive, and included a (partial) `tar tv` listing, showing permissions and users/groups within the tar ball.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. So are you saying that only a person with rootly privileges will be able to extract it with the options to change the ownership? I have updated my question.

Comment: @sayan: the opposite, actually